# Reference in chapter's name. How does it look?

Tags: cross-referencing

Have you ever come across to a reference in chapter's name? More precisely, I'm about to use reference to a equation in the name of one appendix - there is no way to describe that particular equation. E.g.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\begin{equation}
B
\label{equa}
\end{equation}

\appendix
\chapter{Explanation of~\ref{equa}}

\end{document}
```

What do you think about such thing?

Comment: this sort of reference is done, though not frequently.  you should probably be a bit more verbose, for example "Explanation of Equation~(xxx)", and use `\protect\ref` since chapter titles are re-used.